# How to substitute line break on register?

Tags: substitute, register, line-breaks

Suppose the content in register b is: `a^Jbcdefg, ^Jhijkl^J^J`, I want to format it by substituting `^J` with a space to make it looks like this: `a bcdefg,  hijkl`.

I've consulted many documentations but found no answer. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11360856/macvim-modify-the-content-of-the-clipboard-register-before-pasting-it/11362748#11362748) is the closest one on StackExchange.

Here are my commands:

```
let @b=substitute(@b,'^J',' ','g')
let @b=substitute(@b,'\^J',' ','g')
let @b=substitute(@b,'NL',' ','g')
```

I thought maybe the linebreak is not <kbd>^</kbd> appending <kbd>J</kbd> so I just copied it from the register when running `:reg` using the mouse manually, but also got a wrong result.

Can I replace the line break with a space? Or remove the line break?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `\n` to match newlines:

```
let @b=substitute(@b,'\n',' ','g')
```

This also works in `s///`:

```
:%s/\n/ /g
```

If you want to do it the other way around, replace spaces with newlines, it works the way you expect with a register:

```
let @b=substitute(@b,' ','\n','g')
```

**However,** you need to use `\r` instead of `\n` in replacement values in `s///`:

```
:%s/ /\r/g
```

Comment: Thanks very much. I want to know more about this, could you please introduce me the relevant documentation?

Comment: @leoadams There are `:help /\n`, `:help s/\r`, and `:help NL-used-for-Nul`.  Not sure what else to tell you.  Vim is just weird.